# Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

Im trying to call a stored procedure with php and mysql and getting the above error message? Anyone got any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

```
try{
   $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=holidaybookingapp', '', '');
}
catch (PDOException $exception) 
{
   echo "Oh no, there was a problem" . $exception->getMessage();
}

    $startDate="2017-05-23";
    $endDate="2017-05-23";
    $empID= "2";

    $sql='CALL spAddNewHoliday(:EmployeeID,:StartDate,:EndDate)';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL spAddNewHoloiday(?,?,?)");

    $stmt->bindParam('employeeID',$empID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('StartDate1',$startDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam('EndDate1',$endDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    //$array=array($empID, $startDate,$endDate);

    $stmt->execute(); // call the stored procedure
```

Comment: Invalid parameter number seems clear... why do you prepare stmt twice? and, btw, why don't you keep your first stmt and use an array in execute instead of bindParam three times? + notice your "spAddNewHoloiday" that looks wrong... (holoiday)

Comment: you call `prepare` twice. If you call `prepare` like the first time, you have to call `bindParam(':StartDate'....)` (with `:` and without `1` at end); if you call-it like the second way, you have to call `bindParam(1, $empID,...); bindParam(2, $startDate...)  etc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the second prepare(), and the placeholders have to match the same name

```
$startDate="2017-05-23";
$endDate="2017-05-23";
$empID= "2";

$sql='CALL spAddNewHoliday(:EmployeeID,:StartDate,:EndDate)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam('EmployeeID',$empID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam('StartDate',$startDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam('EndDate',$endDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$stmt->execute(); // call the stored procedure
```

Answer (score 1):

Change from :

```
$sql='CALL spAddNewHoliday(:EmployeeID,:StartDate,:EndDate)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

To :

```
$sql='CALL spAddNewHoliday(:EmployeeID,:StartDate,:EndDate)';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':EmployeeID'=>$empID, ':StartDate'=>$startDate, ':EndDate'=>$endDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way :

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("CALL spAddNewHoliday(:emp,:start,:end)");
$stmt->execute([':emp'=>$empID,':start'=>$startDate,':end'=>$endDate]);
```